# How to use Notation package with TraditionalForm

Tags: output-formatting, custom-notation

I know that I can use the `Notation` package to define my own custom notation. This works great for `StandardForm` output, but I would like the notation to apply when I convert it to TraditionalForm`. For example:

```
Notation[△ θ_ ⟸ △[θ_]]
```

This tells *Mathematica* that if it finds a laplacian operator, mathematica should display it without the brackets. This works fine in `StandardForm`. However, if I use `TraditionalForm`, then *Mathematica* inserts parentheses instead of following the rule.

How can I make the rule apply to `TraditionalForm`?

Answer (score 2):

The `Notation` function has the Option `WorkingForm` that defines in which form the notation will be defined. So you have to define your Notation for `StandardForm` **and** `TraditionalForm`

```
Notation[△ θ_ ⟸ △[θ_]]
Notation[△ θ_ ⟸ △[θ_], WorkingForm -> TraditionalForm]
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work

```
Format[△[θ_], TraditionalForm] := HoldForm[△ θ]
```